# How can the hardware store copy my car keyfob?

Tags: encryption, vehicle

I was recently at my local hardware store, where they were offering copies of car keyfobs. They claimed they could copy ''over 90% of cars on the road'' across a number of manufacturers.

I'm wondering how this is possible, given the rolling code encryption used in such keyfobs. I understand a dealership being able to copy keyfobs, presumably with more information available to them from the manufacturer. But how would the hardware store be able to?

My understanding is that it would be impossible to do this by just pressing each button a few times, without incredible computational power. So is there some kind of information that can be extracted off the physical key itself, like an ID?

Or are they taking a more active approach; for example, giving you an entirely new, but compatible, keyfob, which you would then have to reprogram with your car?

And either way, what's preventing this technique from being used by attackers? In the former case, an attacker would just need brief physical access to the key. The attack surface of the latter case depends on the exact reprogramming process, but I'm still curious how that works: for example, if the key is passing its rolling code constants to the car over the air, could an attacker sniff this transmission?

Comment: This video seems to suggest the latter (reprogramming the car) case: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eKDtb1Tbcqc

Comment: I googled the title of your post here and got many high-quality hits. I'm afraid that any answer will simply be a repeat of the easily-searched articles that explain this all.

Comment: I'm wondering more about the actual signalling that's going on - presumably the remote must send the car its rolling code keys, and that seems like an attack vector. If you saw something pertaining to that, I must have missed it - could you pass it along?

Comment: The hits I received talked about the *range* of different technologies used, including rolling codes. I'm afraid that exploring the different car manufacturer's key fob technology options is a little beyond the "information security" domain.